# Adding Permissions for App to List

Tags: list, permissions, csom, provider-hosted-app

I created a list using a provider hosted app. I changed the permissions to that list for a specific usergroup:

```
private void CreateList(string ListName)
{
    Web web = clientContext.Web;

    ListCreationInformation listCreationInfo = new ListCreationInformation
    {
        Title = ListName
    };

    var newList = web.Lists.Add(listCreationInfo);
    AddPermissionsToList(newList);
}

private void AddPermissionsToList(List list)
{
    Log.DebugFormat("[{0}] AddPermissionsToList", ListName);

    var contributor = AppContext.Web.RoleDefinitions.GetByType(RoleType.Contributor);
    var reader = AppContext.Web.RoleDefinitions.GetByType(RoleType.Reader);

    list.BreakRoleInheritance(false, true);
    list.RoleAssignments.Add(GetPermission(contributorGroup), new RoleDefinitionBindingCollection(AppContext) { "EditUsers"});
    list.RoleAssignments.Add(GetPermission(readerGroup), new RoleDefinitionBindingCollection(AppContext) { "ReadUsers" });

    AppContext.ExecuteQuery();
}
```

(`private Group GetPermission(string permissionName)` returns a group when entering the group name as string)

As you can see, the groups "EditUsers" and "ReadUsers" haver write/read permissions to that list.

Now I got the problem that the app itself cannot access the List anymore. It does not even find the lists anymore.

So how can I make sure that the App itself still has access to the lists? (I do not want to add the app to those lists)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end, it was quite simple. Just get the AppOnly-ClientContext and then the "CurrentUser" returns the App-User which then can be added to the list-permissions